# For loop that gets file names from specified folder and all subfolders - js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have two js scripts that I would like to merge into one, but I do not know how.

Script one, uploads all files inside specified folder into virustotal, scans them, and returns the result of the scan.

Script two, lists all files inside the specified folder and all of its subfolders.

I would like to make a script that uploads all files inside specified folder and all of its subfolders into virustotal, scans them, and returns the result of the scan.

How would I go about doing that?

Script one:

```js
/*jshint esversion: 8 */

const path = require('path');
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const VirusTotalApi = require("virustotal-api");
const virusTotal = new VirusTotalApi('<YOUR API KEY>');

const basePath = '/home/username/Desktop/TEST/';
const wait = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));

async function scan() {
    const files = await fsp.readdir(basePath);
    let errors = [];
    for (let file of files) {
        const fullPath = path.join(basePath, file);
        console.log(file);
        try {
            const data = await fsp.readFile(fullPath);
            const response = await virusTotal.fileScan(data, file);
            const resource = response.resource;
            const result = await virusTotal.fileReport(resource);
            const resultLine = `${file}: ${JSON.stringify(result, ["verbose_msg","total","positives"])}\n`;
            await fsp.appendFile('Result.txt', resultLine);
            console.log(`${file}: Saved!`);
        } catch (e) {
            // collect the error, log the error and continue the loop
            e.fullPath = fullPath;
            errors.push(e);
            console.log(`Error processing ${fullPath}`, e);
            continue;
        }
        // Wait for 30 seconds
        await wait(30000);
    }
    // if there was an error, then reject with all the errors we got
    if (errors.length) {
        let e = new Error("Problems scanning files");
        e.allErrors = errors;
        throw e;
    }
}

scan().then(() => {
    console.log("all done scanning - no errors");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Script two:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
const stat = promisify(fs.stat);

async function getFiles(dir) {
  const subdirs = await readdir(dir);
  const files = await Promise.all(subdirs.map(async (subdir) => {
    const res = resolve(dir, subdir);
    return (await stat(res)).isDirectory() ? getFiles(res) : res;
  }));
  return files.reduce((a, f) => a.concat(f), []);
}
getFiles('/home/username/Desktop/TEST')
  .then(files => console.log(files))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few options to get to a result here. The quick and dirty approach is to:

1. eliminate naming conflicts (make sure nothing is named the same between the two files
2. Copy over the consts and the function in file B into file A.
3. Copy the getFiles call in right after the scan().then... call

There are other cleaner approaches. But this should get you to a proof of concept that it is possible to have both scripts function together in a single script.